# How to use OpenGL 3.0 on MacOS with Intel HD 3000

Tags: c++, macos, opengl-3, glfw

I'm trying to set up the OpenGL 3.0 on my xcode, i'm with mac os x 10.9.2 and the latest xcode with all the updates installed.
I configured my project with xcode, the headers files contains gl3.h.
But when i do

```
cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;
```

I get

```
2.1 INTEL-8.18.28
```

Is there a way to specify OpenGL 3.0? i checked and the Intel hd 3000 do have support for OGL 3.0.

Note: I`m using GLFW and i added:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
```

But i get

```
NSGL: The targeted version of OS X does not support OpenGL 3.0 or 3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved With:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```